# end line is not parsing correctly with re library python

Tags: python, regex

Consider the string:

```
<p class="sm clg" data-rlocation="Uttam Nagar East">Uttam Nagar East, Delhi <span class="to-txt" id="citytt1">B-24, East Uttam Nagar, Uttam Nagar East,<br>Delhi<span> - </span>110059
```

I want to get the result `Uttam Nagar East` using a regex function, but the output I'm getting is

```
Uttam Nagar East">Uttam Nagar East, Delhi <span class="to-txt" id="citytt1'
```

I've tried using

```
print(re.findall(r'data-rlocation="(.*)["]',contents))
```

and

```
print(re.findall(r'data-rlocation="(.*)"',contents))
```

Comment: `.` matches everything, so even the closing quote will be matched. Try `print(re.findall(r'data-rlocation="([^"]*)"',contents))`    My change: `[^"]` matches everything except quotes, so it won't match past the end of your "Nagar East" string

Answer (score 3):

The group `(.*)` is including the closing quotes in its capture. Try this instead:

```
>>> re.findall(r'data-rlocation="([^"]*)"', contents)
['Uttam Nagar East']
```

Check out how it works [here](https://regex101.com/r/uN5UsB/1).

Answer (score 1):

By default, `*` is greedy, which means that it tries to consume as many characters as possible. If you'd rather match as *few* characters as possible, you can use the non-greedy qualifier `*?` instead:

```
print(re.findall(r'data-rlocation="(.*?)"',contents))
```

More information: https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy

Comment: That being said, you probably shouldn't be using regex to parse HTML. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1):

you are using greedy regex you can add '?' to make it non greedy

```py
import re
contents = '<p class="sm clg" data-rlocation="Uttam Nagar East">Uttam Nagar East, Delhi <span class="to-txt" id="citytt1">B-24, East Uttam Nagar, Uttam Nagar East,<br>Delhi<span> - </span>110059'
print(re.findall(r'data-rlocation="(.*?)"',contents))
```

Answer (score 1):

A positive lookbehind and positive lookahead with a lazy match will do the trick.

Pattern: `(?<=data-rlocation=").*?(?=")`

Code: `print(re.findall(r'(?<=data-rlocation=").*?(?=")',contents))`

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/h7GFHf/1)

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` use a positive lookahead. It will not return the string. It will only make sure that this pattern is right before the match.

  - `data-rlocation="` this is the string to match
- `)` close the positive lookahead
- `.*` match every single character of the string we want to return
- `?` make the `*` lazy (not greedy)
- `(?=` open a positive lookahead to match the closing pattern but don't return the string

  - `"` match the next double quote
- `)` close the positive lookahead

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, `find_all` from bs4 might return the desired output:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

line = '<p class="sm clg" data-rlocation="Uttam Nagar East">Uttam Nagar East, Delhi <span class="to-txt" id="citytt1">B-24, East Uttam Nagar, Uttam Nagar East,<br>Delhi<span> - </span>110059'
soup = BeautifulSoup(line, 'html.parser')

for l in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(l['data-rlocation'])
```

#### Output

```
Uttam Nagar East
```

---

If not, maybe

```
(?i)data-rlocation="([^\r\n"]*)"
```

with `re.findall` might be another option.

```
import re

expression = r'(?i)data-rlocation="([^\r\n"]*)"'

string = """
<p class="sm clg" data-rlocation="Uttam Nagar East">Uttam Nagar East, Delhi <span class="to-txt" id="citytt1">B-24, East Uttam Nagar, Uttam Nagar East,<br>Delhi<span> - </span>110059
"""

print(re.findall(expression, string))
```

#### Output

```
['Uttam Nagar East']
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ANs1ib/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/ANs1ib/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---